# How to combine several files into one file by adding comma and square brackets

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am writing groovy pipeline script which checks out several files from GIT and should create a single file as newoutput.txt.

**SAMPLE CONTENT**

*File-1*

```
{
  name: "Test-1"
}
```

*File-2*

```
{
  name: "TEST-2"
}
```

*File3*

```
{
  name: "TEST-3",
}
```

**Sample Output: (begins and ends with square brackets, and added commas between each file)**

```
[

    {
      name: "Test-1",
    },

    {
      name: "TEST-2",

    },

    {
      name: "TEST-3",
    }
]
```

I have tried the following command which is working fine on shell but not sure how to rewrite in groovy.

```
echo '[' >> /tmp/newoutput.txt ; 
for i in *.txt; do cat $i ; echo "," ; done >> /tmp/newoutput.txt ; 
sed '$d' /tmp/newoutput.txt ; 
echo "]" >> /tmp/newoutput.txt "
```

Comment: Please add the groovy code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors, stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.  In your example all inner JSON-Blocks around `Test-[12]` got a `,` added in your example.  Also your shell example adds a `,` at the end of the last block, which would be invalid JSON (assuming you are trying to build up JSON here)

Comment: sh " echo '[' >> /tmp/newoutput.txt; for i in *.txt ; do cat $i; echo "," ; done >> /tmp/newoutput.txt ; sed '$d' /tmp/newoutput.txt ; echo "]" >> /tmp/newoutput.txt "

Comment: @cfrick I tried above one as I'm new to groovy but its not accepting and throwing unexpected sh error

Comment: So I assume, you don't care for a groovy solution at all and just want to make your shell script work in jenkins. I'll adjust the tags.

Comment: @cfrick I have a groovy pipeline job and I need to fit this solution in my job.